# Remove prefix and suffix with oracle regex

Tags: regex, string, oracle

I have some records with that come with a prefix and suffix (may or may not come).
I'm trying to figure the `REGEXP_REPLACE` that will always return me a parametrized value.

My attempt so far is:

```
with teste as (
select '+123145@domain.com' as num from dual
union
select '0054321@domain.com' as num from dual
union
select '006789' as num from dual
union
select '+9876' as num from dual
union
select '13579@domain.com' as num from dual
union
select '123456789' as num from dual
)
select REGEXP_REPLACE(num,'^00(.*)\@.*$|^\+(.*)\@.*$','\1') from teste
```

but is not quite there.

The output of that should be:

```
num
12345
54321
6789
9876
13579
123456789
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one here

```
REGEXP_REPLACE(num,'^(00|\+)?(\d*)(\@.*)?$','\2')
```

See it here [online at Regexr](http://regexr.com?2udof)

I am not sure what Oracle regex is able to do. Critical points could be the `\d` meaning a digit, if this is not working replace `\d` with `[0-9]`.

`(?:)` are non capturing groups. The pattern inside is not stored in a capturing group so you can always replace with the first capturing group `\1`

I also changed from your alternatives using `|` to optional parts using `?` after the non capturing groups. The two brackets in your "OR" caused that the result is sometimes in group 1 (when the first alternative is matching) and sometimes in group 2 (when the second alternative is matching)

Comment: Hm.. It works in the regexr (awesome tool by the way, thanks!) but did not behave the same in oracle... could there be differences in the implementation that you'd be aware of?

Comment: I checked on [oracle documentation](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14251/adfns_regexp.htm) `\d` is supported, but I can't find anything about the non capturing groups. So try to remove the two `?:`, but then you need to replace with the second group `\2`

Comment: nailed it. thanks! p.s.: will edit your answer to the regex I'll be using.